# Problema al actualizar datos desde python a BBDD SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

Cuando leo los datos de la BBDD para actualizarlos, me salta el error de syntaxis:

`sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error`

La función que se encarga de actualizar es la siguiente:

````
    #try:
    datosVar=(matriculaVar.get(), itvVar.get(), adrVar.get(), imdgVar.get(), tacografoVar.get(), freeVar.get(), textoComentario.get('1.0',END))
    conexion = sqlite3.connect("Recordatorio-ITV")
    cursor=conexion.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE RECORDATORIO SET ITV=?, ADR=?, IMDG=?, TACOGRAFO=?, FREE=?, NOTES=? WHERE MATRICULA= '"+ matriculaVar.get() +"', (datosVar)")
    #messagebox.showinfo("BBDD","Datos actualizados con éxito")
    conexion.commit()

    #except:

        #messagebox.showwarning("¡Atención!", "Los datos no se han podido actualizar, compruebe que ha ingresado la información correctamente")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes las comillas de cierre en el lugar incorrecto, de forma que incluyes la tupla con los parámetros como cadena en la propia query. Debería sr en todo caso:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE RECORDATORIO SET ITV=?, ADR=?, IMDG=?, TACOGRAFO=?, FREE=?, NOTES=? WHERE MATRICULA= '"+ matriculaVar.get() +"'", datosVar)
```

Pero ya que muy acertadamente parametrizas, parametrizalo todo y no uses concatenado de cadenas o formateo:

```
datos_var = (
    itvVar.get(), adrVar.get(), imdgVar.get(), tacografoVar.get(),  
    freeVar.get(), textoComentario.get('1.0', END), matriculaVar.get()
    )
cursor.execute("""
    UPDATE RECORDATORIO
    SET ITV=?,
        ADR=?,
        IMDG=?,
        TACOGRAFO=?,
        FREE=?,
        NOTES=?
    WHERE MATRICULA=?""",
    datos_var
    )
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas graciasesta mucho más claro así, lo único que he tenido que modificar de tu código para poder funcionar era eliminar el primer matriculaVar.get(), pero ha sido pura lógica al colocarlo tu al final de la tupla y en el propio WHERE,

Comment: Tienes razón, no me había percatado que ya lo incluías pero al principio. Editado. Un saludo.